# use block in include node.js jade

Tags: node.js, include, pug

I am trying to use block in include:

for exemple:
layout.jade

```
!!!5
html
    head
    body
        include header
        #footer footer
        block javascript
            script('src'= 'jquery.js')
```

header.jade

```
h1 header
append javascript
    script
        console.log('Hi, I'm header')
```

I have :

```
<h1>header</h1>
<script>console.log('Hi, I'm header')</script>
<div id="footer" >footer</div>
<script src="jquery.js" ></script>
```

And I would have:

```
<h1>header</h1>
<div id="footer" >footer</div>
<script src="jquery.js" ></script>
<script>console.log('Hi, I'm header')</script>
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

blocks don't work that way with *included* files, as far as I know.  Blocks work with the `extends` feature.  So you could either revise your code to include the javascript as an `include`, or revise it to use `extend`

here's how it might look using `extend`

layout.jade

```
!!!
html
  head
  body
    block header
      h1 header

    block footer
      #footer footer

    block javascript
      script('src'= 'jquery.js')
```

index.jade

```
extends layout

append javascript
  script
    console.log('hi');
```

Comment: Yes but you have to redefine the header in each page with your solution

Comment: well, you could also put the content of the header in layout.jade, just like the jquery script is there.  everything could go in layout.jade, and your index file could just be the `append javascript` block; edited to show this.